# dplyr syntax in R - full join

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm pretty sure I'm going to embarrass myself here with my lack of knowledge of query languages, etc. Hopefully this is a simple query.

If I have two dataframes in R, I want to create what I *thought* was a "full join", which is a table containing one record for each combination of records in the first and the second frames.

So if I set this up (as a very simple example):

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  Col_1 = c("Alan", "Bob")
)

df_2 <- data.frame(
  Year = c(2005, 2006, 2007, 2008)
)
```

I would like to create a data frame that looks like:

```
Col_1   Col_2
=====  =====
Alan    2005
Alan    2006
Alan    2007
Alan    2008
Bob     2005
Bob     2006
Bob     2007
Bob     2008
```

I hoped I could do this using:

```
df_output <- full_join(df_1, df_2)
```

but I get an error message

> Error: `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables

which I understand...but i don't know how to get to where I'm trying to go.

Can anyone help please?
Thanks
Alan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you are looking for a`full_join`, rather a `crossing` from tidyr:

```
tidyr::crossing(df_1, df_2)
```

To give you:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  Col_1  Year
  <fct> <dbl>
1 Alan   2005
2 Alan   2006
3 Alan   2007
4 Alan   2008
5 Bob    2005
6 Bob    2006
7 Bob    2007
8 Bob    2008
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh yes. Not a full join, a CROSS join! I really must learn this stuff properly some time. Thank you. I'll try your suggestion in a moment.

Comment: It worked perfectly! (not just on this simple data set but on some bigger tables) - thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are not looking for a full join but for `expand.grid`:

```
expand.grid(Col_1 = c("Alan", "Bob"), Year = c(2005, 2006, 2007, 2008))

  Col_1 Year
1  Alan 2005
2   Bob 2005
3  Alan 2006
4   Bob 2006
5  Alan 2007
6   Bob 2007
7  Alan 2008
8   Bob 2008
```

I would recommend setting `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, i.e.

```
expand.grid(Col_1 = c("Alan", "Bob"), Year = c(2005, 2006, 2007, 2008),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `full_join` from dplyr there should be a column to join by so add such a column and then remove it afterwards.

```
df_1 %>%
  mutate(join = 0) %>%
  full_join(mutate(df_2, join = 0), by = "join") %>%
  select(-join)
```

giving:

```
  Col_1 Year
1  Alan 2005
2  Alan 2006
3  Alan 2007
4  Alan 2008
5   Bob 2005
6   Bob 2006
7   Bob 2007
8   Bob 2008
```

Note that without any packages or need to add dummy columns we can use `merge`:

```
merge(df_1, df_2)
```